# Finale v26 break top beam of a 16th note

Tags: notation, beaming, finale

[image]

I'm trying to create the above form of notation in finale. All I can muster is the below.[image]

Any insights?

Comment: Was this done with two voices or one? If two, maybe swap them? My thinking is that perhaps Finale places the beam according to which is voice 1 and which is voice 2.

Comment: I'll post an answer this evening when I'm in front of finale, but I believe that you can adjust either the secondary beam height or angle with the special tools palette. This may allow you to move the beam in question up above the one that spans the whole set of notes.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as someone who has only ever tried cross-beaming in Musescore and has never progressed beyond Finale Notepad...but did find in the comments that this is the method that fixed the problem...

Try cross-beaming the notes the other way from before. For example, if you made your example starting with the lower staff and forcing the middle notes to the upper staff, try making your example starting with the upper staff, then forcing the notes at the ends to the lower staff.

Comment: I didn't think starting from a different stave would make a difference, but it seems it does (although flipping the stems is easier), so my DV is unjustified. Please feel free to edit your answer so I can revert it.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. All you need to do is reverse the stem direction (in speedy entry mode: the 'L' key), then move the beams with the beam-angle special tool.